# Akka: First message going to dead letters, from second message it is all fine

Tags: scala, akka

I have supervisor actor which selects child actor based on command received, whenever it creates a new child actor and sends message(ask pattern) it timesout as child actor tries to send back response but it goes to dead letters.

Here is the child actor code

```
class IdActor(id: String, injector: Injector) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case cmd: GenerateIdCmd =>
      val parent = sender()
      ...
      Future(idEvent) pipeTo sender //Issue is here going to dead letters
      //Future(idEvent) pipeTo parent //This also leads to same problem
      //parent ! idEvent // Same issue
  }
}
```

Here is supervisor code

```
class IdSupervisor(injector: Injector) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case cmd: GenerateIdCmd =>
      ...
      val ref = context.child(cmd.id).getOrElse {
        context.actorOf(Props(classOf[IdActor], cmd.id, injector), cmd.id)
      }
      ask(ref, cmd) pipeTo sender
  }
}
```

Second message is flowing back to originator, first response from all new child actors going to dead letters from there afterwards going good.

**Working Solution**
Issue is with Supervisor, fixed code

```
class IdSupervisor(injector: Injector) extends Actor {
      override def receive: Receive = {
        case cmd: GenerateIdCmd =>
          val originator = sender
          ...
          val ref = context.child(cmd.id).getOrElse {
            context.actorOf(Props(classOf[IdActor], cmd.id, injector), cmd.id)
          }
          ask(ref, cmd) pipeTo originator
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the issue doesn't actually occur when a child replies to the parent as you describe, but when the parent sends a message to a child and expects a reply:

```
val ref = context.child(cmd.id).getOrElse {
  context.actorOf(Props(classOf[IdActor], cmd.id, injector), cmd.id)
}
ask(ref, cmd) pipeTo sender
```

An actor is started asynchronously upon creation. The observation that, when a new child is created, the first message to that child results in dead letters, while subsequent messages to that child result in the intended behavior, suggests an actor initialization issue. What's probably happening is that the child actors receive their first `GenerateIdCmd` message before they have completely started.

Comment: Your guess is correct, in supervisor I was sending message to child with in future(flatMap) so sender info is lost. I copied sender before future and used within `flatMap`. Its all working well now.

Comment: Only first message sent in future as supervisor has to fetch some data from database from second message on it was sending direct to child(so no future used here), so from second message on it was all good

Answer (score 1):

Never ever pipe directly to sender from future inside actor, `sender` is `def` and at the moment when future is completed, it might be already different one than you expect. One of solution is to store sender before future call:

```
class IdActor(id: String, injector: Injector) extends Actor {
  override def receive: Receive = {
    case cmd: GenerateIdCmd =>
      ...
      val originalSender = sender
      Future(idEvent) pipeTo originalSender
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried the same result is same, I have edited my code in question. Issue is always happening only for first command

Comment: Note that using `pipeTo` creates this: `PipeableFuture(Future(idEvent)).pipeTo(sender)` which means the `Future` doesn't have to complete before `sender` is resolved. Which means that this doesn't necessarily explain the issue.

Comment: Note that ask pattern itself also returns future, try to store sender also here:
`ask(ref, cmd) pipeTo originalSender`

Comment: This doesn't necessarily explain the issue, but will help to avoid other

Comment: @rethab, seems you are right, in case of pipeTo sender should be resolved before completion of future, so probably not the case